# Remove multiple items by value from dropdownlist C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have one dropdownlist named drpdemo and consist some listitems as shown below

**Design Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdemo" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="213">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Inline Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drpdemo.Items.Remove(drpdemo.Items.FindByValue("0"));
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
Select
  2
  3
  4
  5
  0
```

Above output comes with the 0, which i don't want it in output.

**Expected Output:**

```
Select
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

> **Note: Dont want to use any loop.**

Comment: Please explain your aversion to loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a loop because `Remove` takes one `ListItem` and `FindByValue` returns only one `ListItem`.

To get the items to delete, we can do:

```
var toDelete = drpDemo.Items
               .Cast<ListItem>()
               .Where(i => i.Value == "0");
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach (var item in toDelete)
{
    drpDemo.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Or if you're functionally inclined, do:

```
toDelete.ForEach(i => drpDemo.Items.Remove(i));
```

And all in one:

```
drpDemo.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(i => i.Value == "0")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => drpDemo.Items.Remove(i));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936466/merge-2-or-more-rows-of-a-column-if-other-column-has-same-values-text-in-sqlserv

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully to your drop down list, you will notice that there are **two** items with the **same value**, `0`. So the method `FindByValue` finds the first and then you remove only this. If you had only one `ListItem` with value `0`, then you wouldn't have seen it.

Comment: @Pranav you are correct I tested my code and I deleted it. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

`Dropdown` list does not support any method for removing multiple items at once so you will have to use a loop.

If you're ok with using a loop internally, but simply don't want to write one, you can always use LINQ (though I'll leave it for you to judge if it improves readability vs. using a loop).

```
drpdemo.Items
       .OfType<ListItem>()
       .Where(li => li.Value == "0")
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(li => drpdemo.Items.Remove(li));
```

Comment: @canon - I don't believe anything I wrote suggests doing so. If I missed anything, would you kindly point me to it?

Comment: Getting Error-does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)